# Edit standard modal dialog (iframe) content - SP2013

Tags: 2013, jquery, css, iframe

I am working with SharePoint 2013 and trying to remove the following red-framed section of the standard-generated modal window, which pops-up when checking in a document.

[image]

I do not own SharePoint Designer and I also don't have access to the top level. I am simply a Site Owner of a subsite.

I guess there is an option to work on this problematic using CSS and the display:none feature, but that would mean I have to move the "Kommentare" (engl. comments) section up with CSS.

[image]

So is there maybe any workaround by removing this certain table row?

Probably one also needs jQuery, from what I have researched.

Comment: disable the checkout in the document library? that would remove it

Comment: One should be still able to checkout a document. I just don't want that users have the option, that after checking in a document they still can keep a document checked out (if they for example want to continue editing on it after a short break)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Full Control on the site you'll have the permissions to register a scriptlink iirc.

Create a file on your computer, call it HideRetainCheckout.js or something and add the following:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches)
    Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
                                Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;

if (!Element.prototype.closest)
    Element.prototype.closest = function(s) {
        var el = this;
        if (!document.documentElement.contains(el)) return null;
        do {
            if (el.matches(s)) return el;
            el = el.parentElement || el.parentNode;
        } while (el !== null && el.nodeType === 1); 
        return null;
    };

function ready(fn) {
  if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading"){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

if(decodeURIComponent(window.location.href).indexOf("checkin.aspx?List={D3E77CCA-4514-4543-8656-D1AF54941CE9}") > -1) {
    ready( function() {
        document.querySelector("#KeepCheckoutRadioGroupLabel").closest("td.ms-inputformcontrols").parentNode.style.display = "none"
    });
}
```

Change the part List={D3E77CCA-4514-4543-8656-D1AF54941CE9} to match the listid of your document library. You'll find the id in the URL when you open the list settings.

Upload the file to SiteAssets

To register the script you run the following script one time in the browser console:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();

    var customAction = web.get_userCustomActions().add();
    customAction.set_location('ScriptLink');

    customAction.set_scriptSrc('~site/SiteAssets/HideRetainCheckout.js');
    customAction.set_sequence(9);
    customAction.set_title('HideRetainCheckout');
    customAction.set_description('HideRetainCheckout');
    customAction.update();

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
         console.log('New Support files added to Site.');
    }, function(s,a) {   
        console.log("Error", a.get_message());
    });
});
```

**Update:**

To remove a custom action use the following:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() {
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var userCustomActions = ctx.get_web().get_userCustomActions();
        ctx.load(userCustomActions);

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() { 

            userCustomActions.get_data().forEach(function(action) { 

                if(action.get_title() === "HideRetainCheckout") {
                    action.deleteObject();
                }
            });

            ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() { 
                console.log("Remove UserCustomAction");
            },function(s,a) {
                console.log("error", a.get_message());
            })

        }, function(s,a) { 
            console.log("error", a.get_message());
        });

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your professional answer. Followed your steps and the console.log answered "New Support files added to Site" - but the site won't load anymore now - I have a blank site. What did I do wrong? Or how can I go back to normal settings?

Comment: @SteffPoint whats the error in the console? Just remove the content of the HideRetainCheckout.js. And I'll update my answer with how you remove a custom action too

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: SP is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: I unfortunately can't access anything of the site anymore

Comment: What do you mean with you can't access it? You can't open "https://url to site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx" ?

Comment: yes, it's a blank site suddenly

Comment: Go to another site, change out `var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current()` with `var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("http://urlToYourSite");` and delete the custom action

Comment: Even though it does not make sense that the site is blank, if there was some typo in your HideRetainCheckout it should just crash that script

Comment: The browser console, usually (F12)

Comment: The custom action was removed, but the site still won't load. I even get 404 error now

Comment: ehm, 404, is not found, are you sure the url you are trying to open is correct? Are you sure there is nothing else going on? CustomActions does not delete a site :)

Comment: Will write you in circa 40-50 minutes again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74981/discussion-between-steffpoint-and-anders-aune).